# Linear fit with horizontal and vertical error bars

Tags: regression

I'm searching an equation to calculate the parameters for a linear fit.
With parameters a and b, the $\chi ^{2}$ is used:

$\chi ^{2} = \sum_{i=0}^N (y_{i}-a.x_{i}-b)^{2}$

And with errors:

$\chi ^{2} = \sum_{i=0}^N (\frac{y_{i}-a.x_{i}-b}{\sigma_{i}}) ^{2}$

But now I want to do an analysis on a plot. Every datapoint is a point of two measured data which have both their own error bars. Now I'm thinking about how I can find a $\chi ^{2}$ formula with different error bars on the $x_{i}$ and the $y_{i}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search and asking some people about it, I've found my answer.
Seemed that [deming regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) solves the problem!